# How to suppress the return of shutil.copy2() in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, copy, message, shutil, suppress

It returns the target file path to the console after executing `shutil.copy2()`, which is annoying. [image]

I would like to silent the output.

Comment: Using Python code in REPL to copy a file sounds a bit convoluted. The output should be the least of your worries.

Answer (score -1):

add `_ =`  before `shutil.copy2` will assign the message to `_` to avoid it to be print to console. `_` can be changed to any other names you like.
[image]